# First approach for an electron chat application

Tags: angular, chat, electron, messenger

I'm new to stackoverflow and I was wondering if you people could bring some insight to my problem.

If you were to develop a multiplatform desktop application with electron to chat with your friends (in which you are able to create and join servers, add custom emoticons, send audios, control their desktop, etc.), would you use angular 2/4 for the client side or would that be overkill?

Also, regarding the storage, should I store chat history and user settings in json files, or would it be a good idea to use mongodb storage?

One last thing, is it a good idea to keep the server side and the client side in the same application to allow users to create servers whenever they want?

Thank you, and sorry if I sound too novice there ^^'

Comment: Your app doesnt sound too simple for me . You can use angular for this. Use some db , not json files. I can't answer the last question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you'll need to take one problem at a time and not care too much about the frameworks/libraries. The best option IMHO is to take just any (not 4 years outdated) tutorial for a chat application. It could be in electon, vue, reac, angular or just plain js or whatever. Just follow one. It is not like you'll maintain the software for the next years otherwise this question would be concerning ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I think I'll stick with angular 2 for now :P